# Remove trailing comma from an output loop?

Tags: loop

I want to create a comma separated list of categories to which an entry belongs, but without the trailing slash on the last element... can't work out how to remove it!

```
{% for category in entry.mediaType %}
    <b>{{ category.title }}</b>,
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a special tag inside for loops you can use for this

```
{% for category in entry.mediaType %}
    <b>{{ category.title }}</b>,
    {% if loop.last %}
        <b>{{ category.title }}</b>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Full list [here](https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/8584132#craft-2)

Comment: Awesome, I could not find this anywhere in the Craft docs, thank you!

Comment: You didn't find it in the Craft docs because [it's a native Twig variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

Comment: Is there an advantage to this vs wrapping the "," in a `{% if not loop.last %}`?

Comment: Personal preference.

Answer (score 17):

While your conditional is complete personally preference I would do the following as I find it slightly easier to read. Note the use of the `{%- if -%}` to trim [whitespace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control):

```
{% for category in entry.mediaType %}
    <b>{{ category.title }}</b>
    {%- if not loop.last -%}
      ,
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To clean it up even further: `{{ not loop.last ? "," }}`

Comment: @LindseyD Your suggestion seems very neat but why do I get `unexpected char '?'` ?

Comment: @Pranasas I don’t know. I suggest starting a new thread, since this one is over 3 years old. Feel free to link back to this thread (or answer) for reference.

Answer (score 5):

```
{% for category in entry.mediaType %}
    <b>{{ category.title }}</b>{{ "," if not loop.last }}
{% endfor %}
```