# Access table from Globals in script

Tags: javascript, globals, table

In the `Globals` I have a `field` which is of type `table`. I was trying to access this table in the javascript in order to get the values of particular rows.

```
<script>
        var myTable = "{{ craft.globals.getSetByHandle('myGlobal').myTable }}"; 
</script>
```

It returns a string `"Array"`. If I put `[]` around the expression, it will return `["Array"]`.

Do you know a way to get access to this table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values of your global table field, you need to loop through it.

**somewhere in a template:**

```
{% js %}
    var table = '
    {% for row in global.tableFieldName %}
      ({{ row.column1 }} - {{ row.column2 }}){% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}'
{% endjs %}
```

**Output:**

```
<script>var table = '(Value 1-1 - Value 1-2),(Value 2-1 - Value 2-2)';</script>
```

You should check out the documentation about [Craft 3 Table Fields](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/table-fields.html#settings), [{% js %} Tag](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/js.html) and for removing the trailing comma [Remove trailing comma from an output loop?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/remove-trailing-comma-from-an-output-loop)